# Problems with getcwd syscall on OSX

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, nasm, getcwd

Does anyone have an idea how to get the current working directory in OSX with NASM?  The syscall getcwd isn't available on osx and dtruss pwd return lots of stat sys calls. However in the manual I can't find which structure variable of stat returns the current working directory.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no `syscall` for `getcwd`. It is usually implemented by retrieving `$PWD` environment variable and doing checks to ensure it matches with stat(".") inode and device. You can get an idea of how Apple does it in their [libc code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/getcwd.c) . You could link your assembly language program with `libc` and make the call to `getcwd`.

Comment: so I think for osx it's better to always use the libc library instead like on Linux rely on syscalls only...

Answer (score 2):

That's *a bit* late answer, but nonetheless this can be achieved using 2 syscalls.

1. `open_nocancel` 0x2000018e (or `open` 0x2000005) opening a file descriptor for current dir
2. `fcntl_nocancel` 0x20000196 (or `fcntl` 0x2000005c) for reading the actual path

example:

```
#define F_GETPATH 50     ; from <sys/fcntl.h>

currentDirConstant: 
db   ".",0 ; needs segment read permission  

outputPath:          
resb 1000 ; needs segment write permission

mov rdi,currentDirConstant; input path 1st argument
xor esi, esi        ; int flags 2nd argument, just use 0
xor edx, edx        ; int mode 3rd argument, just use 0
mov eax, 0x2000018e ; open_nocancel syscall number 
syscall        

mov edi,eax          ; file descriptor 1st argument of current dir from previous syscall
mov esi,F_GETPATH    ; fcntl cmd 2nd argument
mov rdx, outputPath  ; output buffer 3rd argument
mov eax, 0x20000196  ; fcntl_nocancel syscall number  
syscall
```