# is there such thing as a getcwd() syscall on macos

Tags: macos, system-calls, getcwd

I am wondering if there is a `getcwd` system call on macos. I can't seem to find any leads on the code for `getcwd` apart from https://www.informatik.htw-dresden.de/~beck/ASM/syscall_list.html. However, the code it gives does not function. I have tried using `objdump -d` on /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib, which according to nm, has a _getcwd function. However, objdump simply raised an error saying that it could not disassemble the file. Could anyone tell me the system call code, if it exists?

Comment: The link you gave is Linux system calls, so it's not surprising that it doesn't work.

Comment: The only tables i could find were linux

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/58181308/5329717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no `getcwd` syscall on macOS. The source for the `getcwd()` library function is [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1353.60.8/gen/FreeBSD/getcwd.c.auto.html). Note, in particular, the comment for the `__getcwd()` internal function: "If __getcwd() ever becomes a syscall, we can remove this workaround."

The Unix syscall table is [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-6153.61.1/bsd/kern/syscalls.master.auto.html). The Mach syscall table (using a separate domain/namespace) is [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-6153.61.1/osfmk/kern/syscall_sw.c.auto.html).